# Google chart "K" instead of thousands

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm using google charts tools (https://developers.google.com/chart/) for displaying data, sometimes my values are really high (100.000+).

My graphs are pretty small in dimensions and 100.000 doesn't fit in, but 100k would.
Is there a way I can configure vAxis to display numbers on vAxis in "K" if there are values higher than 10k?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Google Visualization uses a subset of the [ICU Decimal Format](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classDecimalFormat.html#_details), which can be set either with a `DataView`, or with `vAxis.format`.

Unfortunately, that subset does not include the ability to divide by 1,000. So you will need to manipulate your data first. Let's say this is your data:

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'Data'],
    ['A', 123456],
    ['B', 234567],
    ['C', 456789],
    ['D', 890123],
    ['E', 789012],
    ['F', 789012],
    ['G', 890123],
    ['H', 456789],
    ['I', 234567],
    ['J', 345678],
    ['K', 345678],
    ['L', 345678],
    ['M', 123456],
    ['N', 123456]
  ]);
```

We need to clone the data, and then divide each point by 1,000. Here is a simple way to do that:

```
  var formattedData = data.clone();
  for (var i = 0; i < formattedData.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    var dataPoint = formattedData.getValue(i, 1);
    formattedData.setValue(i, 1, dataPoint / 1000);
  }
```

We can then chart this and set the format as: `vAxis: {format: "#,###k"}` -- but there's an issue. Now when you mouseover the series, you notice that 890,123 displays as 890.123! This is no good, so we need to fix that by adding another line to the loop:

```
  var formattedData = data.clone();
  for (var i = 0; i < formattedData.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    var dataPoint = formattedData.getValue(i, 1);
    formattedData.setValue(i, 1, dataPoint / 1000);
    formattedData.setFormattedValue(i, 1, dataPoint.toString());
  }
```

This will make the data look like 890123, but plot as 890.123 so the axis looks nice. If you want to add commas, there are resources like [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/rajeshatdotnet/archive/2008/04/05/121058.aspx) and [this](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/numberFormat.html) you can use if you'd like. I will not assume to know your data format, so I'll let you figure that part out on your own if you want thousands separators, or decimals, or whatever when you mouseover the chart.

Here is the final working code:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'Data'],
    ['A', 123456],
    ['B', 234567],
    ['C', 456789],
    ['D', 890123],
    ['E', 789012],
    ['F', 789012],
    ['G', 890123],
    ['H', 456789],
    ['I', 234567],
    ['J', 345678],
    ['K', 345678],
    ['L', 345678],
    ['M', 123456],
    ['N', 123456]
  ]);

  // Clone data and divide by 1,000 in column 1
  var formattedData = data.clone();
  for (var i = 0; i < formattedData.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    var dataPoint = formattedData.getValue(i, 1);
    formattedData.setValue(i, 1, dataPoint / 1000);
    formattedData.setFormattedValue(i, 1, dataPoint.toString());
  }

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(formattedData, {curveType: "function",
                  width: 500, height: 400,
                  vAxis: {format: "#,###k"}}
          );
}
```

Answer (score 24):

Briefly,

```
options['vAxis']['format'] = 'short';
```

Comment: I don't know why this isn't the selected answer. This should be the top answer.

Answer (score 5):

[Number Formats](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes), You can control the formatting of label numbers with hAxis.format and vAxis.format.

For instance, {hAxis: { format:'#,###%'} } displays the values "1,000%", "750%", and "50%" for values 10, 7.5, and 0.5. You can also supply any of the following presets:

```
{format: 'none'}: displays numbers with no formatting (e.g., 8000000)
{format: 'decimal'}: displays numbers with thousands separators (e.g., 8,000,000)
{format: 'scientific'}: displays numbers in scientific notation (e.g., 8e6)
{format: 'currency'}: displays numbers in the local currency (e.g., $8,000,000.00)
{format: 'percent'}: displays numbers as percentages (e.g., 800,000,000%)
{format: 'short'}: displays abbreviated numbers (e.g., 8M)
{format: 'long'}: displays numbers as full words (e.g., 8 million)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the [displayExactValues](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline#Configuration_Options) configuration option to `true`:

> Whether to display a shortened, rounded version of the values on the
>   top of the graph, to save space; false indicates that it may. For
>   example, if set to false, 56123.45 might be displayed as 56.12k.

This should give you the behaviour you want, although it doesn't give you the explicit ability to set the value at which you want it to start using the 'k' suffix.

Comment: This seem to be the case for only "Annotated Time Line", I'm using line and bar charts.